# Resolve supression of negative values in cv2::filter2D()

Tags: python, opencv, convolution

I'm using a convolution to calculate the gradient in an image. For this I used OpenCV's `cv2.filter2D()` function, implemented in Python. I also coded a (slow) implementation that simply iterates over all pixels. The input image `img` is a .JPG image converted from RGB to YUV using `cv2.cvtColor()` and split using the OpenCV function `cv2.split()`. A summary of my code (only calculating for one color channel) is:

```
imgYUV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
clr1, clr2, cl3 = cv2.split(imgYUV)
(iH,iW) = clr1.shape[:2]
pad=1
paddedImg = cv2.copyMakeBorder(clr1,pad,pad,pad,pad,cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
outputMyImplementation = np.zeros((iH,iW), dtype='int32')
kernel = np.array([[-1,-2,-1],[0,0,0],[1,2,1]])
for y in np.arange(pad, iH+pad):
    for x in np.arange(pad, iW+pad):
        roi = paddedImg[y-pad:y+pad+1, x-pad:x+pad+1]
        k = (roi*kernel).sum()
        outputMyImplementation[y-pad,x-pad] = k
outputCV2 = cv2.filter2D(clr1,-1,kernel)
```

However, filter2D seems to trim negative values from the input image:

- Max value using filter2D(): 66
- Max value using my implementation(): 66
- Min value using filter2D(): 0
- Min value using my implementation(): -146

Using the flipped kernel `kernel = np.array([[1,2,1],[0,0,0],[-1,-2,-1]])` the results are:

- Max value using filter2D(): 146
- Max value using my implementation(): 146
- Min value using filter2D(): 0
- Min value using my implementation(): -66

It is clear that the negative values are surpressed. All default settings in `cv2.filter2D()` are fine for me, which is why I use minimal arguments. The documentation does not mention this behaviour and multiple forums suggest that negative values should not be surpressed. Does someone know why this happens, and how it can be resolved? I have a workaround by summing the results of the kernel and it's flipped variant, however this seems a bad solution to a simple problem.

Version info:

- `openCV` version 4.4.0.44
- `numpy` version 1.19.2
- `python` version 3.8.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution lies in the depth of the output. By setting it to -1, the depth of the input image is used for the output. As the input image is most likely *uchar*, it saturates to 0. The problem of saturation to zero can be resolved by setting the output type to *cv2.CV_64F* using:

`outputCV2 = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_64F, kernel)`

To get the exact same answer as outputMyImplementation, the kernel must be flipped 180 degrees. When looking at the absolute values, this is however not needed and the code can be used as presented.